# How can I achieve partial application of a function before using it within a magrittR pipeline?

Tags: r, dplyr, magrittr

I want to have parameterizable parts of pipelines.

This is the code I want to write:

```
library(magrittr)
d <- data.frame(x=1:5)
add_n <- function(n) . %>% transform(x = x + n)
d %>% add_n(3)
```

Obviously it doesn't work, because `%>%` sets `d` as the argument of `add_n`.

Comment: Sorry, my bad I edited the question and entered the library to make the minimal example work. Will change to `magrittr` - didn't see the tag in the first palce.

Comment: New trend is getting downvoted because someone edits my questions?

Comment: @DavidArenburg I wanted to keep it simple, that's why I chose `add_n`. My actual use case**s** are more complicated and there are no built-in functions for them.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, tidyr also exports `%>%` (and stringr too, btw)

Comment: @docendodiscimus yeah [newer features it seems](https://github.com/hadley/tidyr/releases/tag/v0.3.0), funny it is categorized under "BUGS" (or maybe it is under "miner improvements"?)

Comment: @ziggystar I haven't downvoted you.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, it's actually called "Bug fixes and minor improvements"..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
add_n <- function(d, n) d %>% transform(x = x + n)
d %>% add_n(3)
#   x
# 1 4
# 2 5
# 3 6
# 4 7
# 5 8
```

`%>%` substitutes the first argument of the following function with the LHS, so your function needs a second argument.

Comment: Uhm, now I'm embarrassed. I have no idea why I didn't get to this solution myself.